# Image previewer for webpages

Tags: javascript, html, flash, image

I am creating a webpage in html with php.

I want the user to be able to click on a small icon image.  When the icon is clicked a preview of a larger image appears.

Guessing the solution probably involves javascript or flash.  Can you point me to the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)?

A Lightbox allows you to have thumbnails of images on your page and when a user clicks on them, the larger image will popup in the middle of the screen. It's very common.

If what you are really looking for is a show/hide effect, you could use JavaScript to show the larger image if the user clicks on the smaller image. A JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) will make it very easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it in php, then may as well use GD to do it for you.

Here's an excellent article to get you started: http://icant.co.uk/articles/phpthumbnails/